# Maven does not include resources files

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

Maven does not include resources files in the generated war file (I went inside webapps in tomcat, `WEB-INB/classes/.`.. that I have in /src/main/resources/   I generate the war using Eclipse neon, The application is an Spring application 3.0.5.RELEASE. I deploy the app in a tomcat server version 7

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.codenvy.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>BikesApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringDemo</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If you *went inside webapps in tomcat*, did you actually check the generated WAR file inside `target`? Can you try by cleaning first `mvn clean package`?

Comment: yes, I did it 100 times

Comment: uep ! I see the files inside the war but not the decompressed war inside the tomcat/webapps  (?)  . I even use the tomcat manager tu upload the war with the same result !

Comment: Was the WAR updated in Tomcat? Remove the decompressed folder and put the new WAR.

Comment: it works, Thanks !